# How do I obtain an SSL Certificate for my Wordpress website that was created on AWS EC2

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, certbot

I recently created a website for a small business and am essentially at the last part of launching it live. The web design is complete, elastic IP is assigned, and domain name is linked. The last step (at least I hope) before promoting the site is obtaining an SSL certificate for the web server so that the "not secure" is no longer at the top by the URL.

I've searched endlessly on the web via YouTube, AWS Help, StackOverflow threads, and have even consulted with my professors, yet I have still not found a proper guide that walks through the process (at least for my circumstances).

My web server is running Apache on Amazon Linux. I'm getting pretty desperate trying to find answers. I'm an undergrad student, so I am not the most knowledgeable on this topic. Previously I have only created a very basic website for previous class projects, so this independent project is a technical step up where all the issues I've had, I've been able to troubleshoot using online resources until now.

Previously I have tried using ACM (Amazon Certificate Manager) to submit a certificate request for my web server, but that failed.

I have also tried using CertBot but there was no guide for my HTTP website which runs Apache on Amazon Linux

I have seen a lot of tutorials use varying methods such as first creating other infrastructures like security groups or load balancers on AWS. I have not touched those toolsets when I created this website. I've only used EC2 plus the connect console to install WordPress, and AWS elastic IP to assign to the instance.

My domain name is on CloudFlare also if that helps with this overall issue.

Comment: I'd start by looking to see if letsencrypt has information on your setup. From a quick search I found this result on their forum. https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/how-to-install-an-ssl-certificate-on-an-aws-ec2-instance/202218

Comment: Are you using your own custom domain name, or are you using a CloudFlare domain name? See also: [Enable SSL access over HTTPS with Cloudflare](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/faq/administration/enable-ssl-cloudflare/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using binami for your wordpress linux instance and you have configured the dns correctly, you should be able to use letsencrypt after you ssh into the ec2 as a way to create the SSL Certificate as someone has already mentioned.

if you can ssh into the instance run:

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/bncert-tool
```

Source: https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/get-started-wordpress-aws-marketplace-intermediate/